# json object to VB.Net array / Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, rest, json.net

I have been tasked with adding a REST server to our company to work with an outside vendor.  I have been able to complete most of it using VB.Net. However I am not sure how to handle the example below where there are 3 descriptors (OrderNumber,Desination,ItemNumbers) and ItemNumbers is an array. There may be any number of ItemNumbers in a single post.  For the others I have made a class with properties, how can I do this with an array? I am using Newtonsoft.Json. Please post an example and Thank You!

```
Public Class Quality 'Example of how I have done the other json Posts
    Private OrderNumberValue As String
    Public Property OrderNumber() As String
        Get
            Return OrderNumberValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            OrderNumberValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private DestinationValue As String
    Public Property Destination() As String
        Get
            Return DestinationValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            DestinationValue = value
        End Set
    End Property
END CLASS
```

This is the example json being posted:

```
{
"OrderNumber": "SO-1234567890",
"Destination": "Dock1 / Floor / whatever",
"ItemNumbers": [
{
"ItemNumber": "400100",
"CasesRequired": "140"
},
{
"ItemNumber": "400200",
"CasesRequired": "140"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Newtonsoft.Json

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Dim order As Order = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Order)(json)
```

and you need two classes

```
 Public Class ItemNumber
        Public Property ItemNumber As String
        Public Property CasesRequired As String
    End Class

    Public Class Order 
        Public Property OrderNumber As String
        Public Property Destination As String
        Public Property ItemNumbers As ItemNumber()
    End Class
```

Comment: I get an error "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Json' accepts this number of arguments" on the line "Dim order As Order = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Order)(json)"  This is the code:   'Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As Order)
            Dim orders As Order = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Order)(Json) '(value)
        End Sub'    Also how can I read the "orders" without know how many items there may be? Thank you!

Comment: @FredSmith I don't have ...Order)(Json) '(value)   value in my code you should just copy paste my code.   don't add anything extra

Comment: I have tried the code below and still receive the error.  Also how can I access or loop through the Orders. Thank You , I am trying to learn!
```
Public Class ItemNumber
    Public Property ItemNumber As String
    Public Property CasesRequired As String
End Class

Public Class Order
    Public Property OrderNumber As String
    Public Property Destination As String
    Public Property ItemNumbers As ItemNumber()
End Class
  
Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As Order)
    Dim orders As Order = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Order,)(Json)
End Sub```